# Brother DCP-110c integrated scanner not working in Mint (18.1 x64)

Tags: linux-mint, usb, printer, scanner, brother

I have successfully installed the printer drivers as indicated [here](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/02/04/how-to-install-brother-dcp-110c-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu-linux-easy-guide/), which should include the scanner drivers.

Indeed, `brscan2` and `brscan-key` are installed; I have also installed `brother-udev-rule-type1`; `sane`, `sane-utils` and `xsane` are installed too.

**The printer is connected through USB and it works (is able to print)**, but  the integrated scanner cannot be used.

Until this point `simple-scan` or `xsane` cannot see the scanner, not even if run with `sudo`.

[image]

[image]

---

**Scanner becomes  visible in the Simple Scan and Xsane settings after copying `/usr/lib64/sane` to `/usr/lib`** (as suggested [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321613&p=13477456#post13477456)). But then `simple-scan` gives a different error ("Unable to start scan") and `xsane` says "Failed to open device 'brother2:bus2;dev3':Invalid argument". - The same with `sudo`.

[image]

[image]

---

Adding

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

in `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` didn't help either.

---

#### Edit

after answer by [pfnuesel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/58056/pfnuesel):

`lssub` gives:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f9:0169 Brother Industries, Ltd DCP-110C RemovableDisk
```

then I did `sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/001/008` with no effect, as this is not (I guess) a permissions problem.

---

I have also tried without success to copy file from `/usr/lib64` and `/usr/lib64/sane` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, as indicated [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321613&page=3) and [here](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1988903).

---

Looking at this post [here](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=21566504#p21566504) which mentions an advanced usb configuration in BIOS (the one discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/480045/what-does-the-bios-setting-xhci-pre-boot-mode-do) - see also the image there) which may be needed for the present purpose, I have found a similar but somewhat different setting.

The above setting is also mentioned [here](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/imprimantes_brother), along other settings that I have tried to follow, but none worked.

I see no XHCI pre boot option in my BIOS - but I see "USB Mass storage driver support" which is enabled.

[image]

Disabling it changes nothing in any of the two usb ports (one is 2.0, the other 3.0).

---

### update

after following [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321613&page=3&p=13480927#post13480927) that says to use

```
export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=128
scanimage -L
```

look for errors of the form `No such file or directory` and copy the specified file at the specified location, I only got these errors:

```
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1'
[dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1' (No such file or directory)
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1'
[dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1' (No such file or directory)
[dll] load: couldn't find backend `v4l' (No such file or directory)
```

But these files seem absent (tested with `locate`)... and, based on the answer to my separate question on this matter ([What is `libsane-v4l.so.1` and how do I get it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/359241/32012)), they are probably not needed for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different scanner and a different OS, so my help might be of limited value. But let's try anyway.

When you plug in the printer, you can run `lsusb` to find out what bus number and what device number is assigned to your printer.

Then grant write permissions to your device

```
chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/$BUS/$DEVICE
```

where `$BUS` and `$DEVICE` are the bus and device numbers noted earlier. Then try again to scan with `xsane`.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. It looks like it addresses a permission issue; in this case it would have already worked with sudo, but I stated in the question that it doesn't.