# What is `libsane-v4l.so.1` and how do I get it?

Tags: printer, scanner, sane

Trying to fix a scanner problem ([Brother DCP-110c scanner not working in Mint 18.1)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/359210/32012), and following [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321613&page=3&p=13480927#post13480927) that says to use

```
export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=128
scanimage -L
```

in order to look for errors of the form `No such file or directory` and copy the specified file at the specified location, I only got these errors:

```
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1'
[dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1' (No such file or directory)
[dll] load: trying to load `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1'
[dll] load: couldn't open `/usr/lib/sane/libsane-v4l.so.1' (No such file or directory)
[dll] load: couldn't find backend `v4l' (No such file or directory)
```

But these files seem absent (tested with `locate`)...

Comment: It is a dynamically linked library, you should be able to install in using `apt`. First search in the repositories for it `apt search libsane`.

Comment: On my system (Arch Linux), this library comes with `sane`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those errors simply mean that `scanimage` tried to load the [`v4l`](http://sane.alioth.debian.org/man/sane-v4l.5.html) backend, but failed. That’s not particularly surprising, because the `v4l` backend isn’t well supported nowadays (if at all) — it was designed for the old V4L kernel API, and as far as I’m aware hasn’t been updated to the current API (V4L2). On Debian derivatives (including Mint), it’s [disabled](https://tracker.debian.org/news/677851).

In any case, none of that matters for your scanner: the V4L backend allows video input devices such as webcams to be used as scanners. It’s irrelevant for your printer.